# How can I dial up ADSL router automatically in windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any way to dial ADSL router up when startup Windows XP?

I don't want to install any software for this simple task. I prefer method which edit the register.

Comment: do you mean connect to internet when computer starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the code below as a .reg file and run it as administrator.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"KeepRasConnections"=dword:00000001
```